# Does Having Too Many NoIndexed Pages Hurt Your Google Rankings?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, noindex

I have a site like reddit. So 99% pages are thin content. I have no-index all pages.

The quality articles are only blog posts written by our team ( Now have around 50 blog posts with 1000-2500 words).

But I saw only very little SEO traffic ( around just 20-50 page views per day) for those pages even web site is 1 year old. What is the reason for it? Is it a problem having too many no-index pages? I can't index them also because those are low quality.

Comment: You are thinking backwards. It is not the posts that you noindex, but the posts that you allow. With just 50 posts, you cannot expect a lot of traffic. As well, it is also about topics. Are people searching for the content you have and how do you stack up to the competition? These are the things you have to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with above comment.

Your thin content not being indexed shouldn't be the issue.

You may like to think/consider about following:

1. Firstly, check if those 20-50 visits are organic, get the real data.
2. You also need to think about the niche popularity and have rich content in a popular niche.
3. These days Google does amazing job ranking rich content with lot less effort but its not always the case. Example if your content may have more competition then just rich content may not do well. So, you need to market your content using various techniques like social, effective backlink strategy etc.